# Simplifying KML for use with D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am working with D3 Maps and have a fairly [large KML](https://www.nemezisproject.co.uk/2012/05/21/google-maps-api-uk-counties-overlay-kml/). On each path I have a `mouseover` event attached that changes colour and displays a tooltip. All works, but the size of the polygon paths and their complexity slows interactivity down.

For my intended purpose, it is not necessary to have such high detail for the map. So I would like to slim down my KML and the polygons inside it, [similar to this](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/simplify/) but without the interactivity.

**MAP CODE**

```
var width  = 1000;
var height = 1100;
var rotate = 60;        // so that [-60, 0] becomes initial center of projection
var maxlat = 55;        // clip northern and southern poles (infinite in mercator)

// normally you'd look this up. this point is in the middle of uk
var center = [-1.485000, 52.567000];

// instantiate the projection object
var projection = d3.geo.conicConformal()
                  .center(center)
                  .clipAngle(180)
                  // size of the map itself, you may want to play around with this in
                  // relation to your canvas size
                  .scale(10000)
                  // center the map in the middle of the canvas
                  .translate([width / 2, height / 2])
                  .precision(.1);

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, 15])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

var svg = d3.select('#map').append('svg')
            .attr('width', width)
            .attr('height', height);

var g = svg.append("g");

svg.call(zoom).call(zoom.event);

var tooltip = d3.select("body")
  .append('div')
  .style('position', 'absolute')
  .style('z-index', '10')
  .style('visibility', 'hidden')
  .attr('class', 'county-info')
  .text('a simple tooltip');


var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);

d3.json("data/map-england.json", function(err, data) {

  g.selectAll('path')
    .data(data.features)
    .enter().append('path')
      .attr('d', path)
      .attr('class', 'border')
      .attr('stroke-width', '.5')
      .attr('id', function(d) { return d.properties.Name.replace(/ /g,'').toLowerCase(); })
      .on("mouseover", function(d) {
        d3.select(this).classed("active", true );
        tooltip
          .style('left', (d3.event.pageX - 15) + 'px')
          .style('top', (d3.event.pageY - 50) + 'px')
          .text(d.properties.Description)
          .style("visibility", "visible");
      })
      .on("mouseout", function(d) {
        d3.select(this).classed("active", false );
        tooltip.style('visibility', 'hidden');
      });
});

function zoomed() {
  g.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}
```

Is there an online tool where I can upload my KML and have it give me back the same KML but simplified?

If not, are there any easy examples that show how one could simplify the paths without any extra interactive code?

Comment: you can use http://geojson.io to convert the KML to topo or geojson and then use the command line tool [topojson](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki/Command-Line-Reference) to simplify the resulting file

Comment: Thanks @TomP. I tried, but it wouldn't even install for me! I get the following error! http://i57.tinypic.com/15hmnna.png

Comment: I've had a lot of trouble getting node and topojson installed, too. That error looks familiar, but I couldn't tell you how I overcame it.

Luckily, there are alternatives, e.g., http://mapstarter.com/

Comment: That is a nice site! unfortunately I can't see how it would simplify the polygons!

Comment: looks like you need python installed too this is often the case if you're doing GIS stuff as so many libraries are written in python.

Comment: @Ciwan's comment reminds me that the web based http://www.mapshaper.org/ might be of help

Comment: It turns out getting `topojson` installed with NodeJS on Windows is a **real pain**. I have gone ahead and installed Ubuntu in a VM just to get this working. What command does one run to simplify the `topojson file`?

Comment: D'oh! Mapshaper is what I was thinking of, not mapstarter.

@Ciwan, have you looked at the command line reference? https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki/Command-Line-Reference

-s to simply and -q to quantize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[D3 Map Pan and Zoom Performance on Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28235034/d3-map-pan-and-zoom-performance-on-chrome)

I had to simplify the paths using the node TopoJson package as Tom suggested. However I couldn't get this to work in Windows! So much hassle with dependencies and pack versions ...etc.

After much pain, I decided getting it to work in Windows was mission impossible. So I went and created a Virtual Machine running Ubuntu. I was up and running with node and TopoJson in no time.

After simplifying the paths, the map, hover and everything was super smooth.