# D3 Map Pan and Zoom Performance on Chrome

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, d3.js

To make things easier, here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3twag6Lx/) of what I have.

**TRY**

In FireFox (version 35.0.1) pan the map. Click and hold anywhere on the map, and move it about quickly left and right. Panning movement should be quick and smooth.

Now try the same in Chrome and you'll see that it is not as smooth! It is a bit jerky/laggy. I find it laggy in the latest version of IE and Opera too.

By the way, if you comment out this style block, then behaviour all of a sudden smooths out and stops being laggy! You won't get a nice map of course.

```
#map path {
    fill: #C9DCC9;
    stroke: #066860;
}
```

**SO WHAT?**

First of all I would appreciate it if someone can confirm this behaviour on their PCs. I am on Windows 8.1 with all latest updates.

And then, why isn't this behaviour happening on other maps done with D3? [This one](http://techslides.com/demos/d3/d3-worldmap-boilerplate.html) for example behaves smoothly! Is it to do with the complexity of the polygons?

Comment: I can confirm that panning/zooming is rather laggy in Chrome40/Win7, and that the lag disappears if you get rid of the stroke (note that the other map you linked to doesn't include strokes).  I don't see a problem in your code: you're using global transforms to do panning and zooming, which should be as optimized as you can get.  Chrome dev tools confirm the lags, and attribute it to a mix of slow paint cycles and repeated update/composite layer cycles.  For panning, it also seems to be buffering multiple events before triggering a repaint.  Best suggestion: file a bug report with Chrome.

Comment: P.S.  I just tested in IE11, the performance is not as good as Firefox but definitely not as bad as Chrome.  Opera uses the same rendering code as Chrome (Blink rendering engine), so filing the [Chrome bug](http://chromiumbugs.appspot.com) will address them both.

Comment: [Using 1ms-long d3 transitions to reduce the DOM changes to once per paint cycle](http://jsfiddle.net/3twag6Lx/1/)  (transitions use `requestAnimationFrame()`) seems to help with zoom, but not with pan.  Chrome seems to be processing the mousemove events one after another with no time to repaint the screen in between.

Comment: I have [logged a chrome bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=454313), please up vote it to get their attention :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this, I simplifed the paths of the map. I used the `-simplification` function on [TopoJson](https://www.npmjs.com/package/topojson).

After the simplification of the paths, the map panning and zooming was super smooth in Chrome, Firefox, Opera and IE 11.

TopoJson is a node package, so you would need to install node and a lot of other dependencies for TopoJson to get it working on windows. If you're lucky it'll work for you on Windows.

I was unlucky so I went and created a Virtual Machine running Ubuntu and in there, the node setup was soo much easier, I managed to do what I wanted in 5 minutes. Compared to days attempting to get this working on Windows.

Anyways, hope this helps. :)

Comment: This was driving me crazy. Indeed, rounding the path data worked for me. Cheers